# Unity Upload Image To Server With Codeigniter Not Working

Tags: c#, php, codeigniter, unity-game-engine

I want to upload an image jpg to my server. I have try but it didn't work.

I don't what cause the upload failed.

Below the detail code.

**Unity C#**

```
public void TakePicture(int maxSize)
    {
        if (NativeCamera.IsCameraBusy())
        {
            Debug.Log("Camera Busy");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            NativeCamera.Permission permission = NativeCamera.TakePicture((path) =>
            {
                Debug.Log("Image path: " + path);
                if (path != null)
                {
                    // Create a Texture2D from the captured image                                        
                    Texture2D texture = NativeCamera.LoadImageAtPath(path, maxSize);
                    //snap.SetPixels(tex.GetPixels());                    

                    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                    Debug.Log("Bytes:" + bytes);
                    Destroy(texture);

                    StartCoroutine(upload_ocr_image(bytes));

                    if (texture == null)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("Couldn't load texture from " + path);
                        return;
                    }

                    // Assign texture to a temporary quad and destroy it after 5 seconds
                    GameObject quad = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);
                    quad.transform.position = Camera.main.transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * 2.5f;
                    quad.transform.forward = Camera.main.transform.forward;
                    quad.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, texture.height / (float)texture.width, 1f);

                    Material material = quad.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
                    if (!material.shader.isSupported) // happens when Standard shader is not included in the build
                        material.shader = Shader.Find("Legacy Shaders/Diffuse");

                    material.mainTexture = texture;

                    Destroy(quad, 5f);

                    // If a procedural texture is not destroyed manually, 
                    // it will only be freed after a scene change
                    Destroy(texture, 5f);

                }
            }, maxSize);

            Debug.Log("Permission result: " + permission);
        }

    }

    IEnumerator upload_ocr_image(byte[] bytes)
    {
        // UtilityScript.GetComponent<utility>().Sand_Clock_Loading(true);

        // yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.5f);

        WWWForm formDate = new WWWForm();

        formDate.AddField("frameCount", Time.frameCount.ToString());
        formDate.AddBinaryData("ocr_image", bytes, "ocr.jpg", "image/jpg");

        formDate.AddField("phone_code", "+61");
        formDate.AddField("phone_number", "434599859");                     

        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(web_url.url_upload_ocr_image, formDate))
        {
            yield return www.Send();

            //UtilityScript.GetComponent<utility>().Sand_Clock_Loading(false);

            if (www.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
               // UtilityScript.GetComponent<utility>().MessageBox_Check_Connection();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log(www.downloadHandler.text);                
            }
        }
    }
```

**And this the code in server codeigniter php.**

```
function upload_ocr_image()
    {           
        $phone_code = $this->input->post('phone_code', true);
        $phone_number = $this->input->post('phone_number', true);

        $allowedType = array(IMAGETYPE_GIF,IMAGETYPE_JPEG,IMAGETYPE_PNG);
        $imgType = exif_imagetype($_FILES['ocr_image']['tmp_name']);
        if(!in_array($imgType,$allowedType))
        {
            echo "Images Type Error. Images Type Only : GIF , JPEG, PNG";
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            //upload original size front end slider
            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/ocr_image/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
            $config['file_name'] = $phone_code.$phone_number;
            $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
            $config['max_size'] = '8096';
            $config['max_width']  = '6000';
            $config['max_height']  = '6000';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if(!$this->upload->do_upload("ocr_image"))
            {
                echo "Maximum File Size Only 2 Mb Or Max Width = 2000 , Height = 2000";
                exit;
            }
            else
            {
                $img_data = $this->upload->data();

                // Create Thumbnail
                /*
                $magicianObj = new imageLib("assets/ocr_image/".$img_data["file_name"].$phone_code.$phone_number);
                $magicianObj -> resizeImage(80, 80, 0, true);
                $magicianObj -> saveImage("assets/admin/img/photos/".$img_data["raw_name"]."_thumb".$img_data["file_ext"], 100);

                $next_id = $next_id.$img_data["file_ext"];
                $thumb_name = $img_data["raw_name"]."_thumb".$img_data["file_ext"];             

                $data = array("photo_name"=>$next_id,
                              "thumb_photo_name"=>$thumb_name,
                              "create_date"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

                $this->db->insert("gallery_tbl",$data);
                */

            }
        }   
    }
```

*No error found. But it always failed.*

**This line of code in codeigniter PHP :**

> if(!$this->upload->do_upload("ocr_image"))

Always return **true**.

How it work ?, How to upload the picture with proper way ?

**Edited :**

I use an asset native camera android and ios from unity to take a picture from camera.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the problem.

Just set allowed type extension to except all extension in codeigniter upload file.

change :

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
```

to

```
$config['allowed_types'] = '*';
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add  initialize `$this->upload->initialize($config);` after
$this->load->library('upload', $config); and check, also check upload directory path is right ? and directory permission

Comment: not working. The problem is not in the PHP, because i try it with postman and it is worked. The problem is in unity